# Can't retrieve string and embedded data from MongoDB, Doctrine ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

My Documents

```
/**
 * Class CellCoordinates
 *
 * @package Community\UserBundle\Document
 *
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class CellCoordinates
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\Float
 */
protected $latitude;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Float
 */
protected $longitude;
```

and

```
/**
 * Class CellStatus
 *
 * @package Community\UserBundle\Document
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="cell_status")
 * @MongoDB\Index(keys={"cell_coordinates"="2d"})
 */
class CellStatus
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Int
 */
protected $cellId;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
protected $type;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Timestamp
 */
protected $timestamp;

/** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Community\UserBundle\Document\CellCoordinates") */
protected $location;
```

I'm trying to retrieve data from Documents in this way:
`$cellStatus->getType()` and `$cellStatus->getLocation()->getLatitude()`,but got nothing.
All that ways returns null.

But I can see data in that fields, when I'm querying mongoDB via shell.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was mysteriously resolved after update.